# What is the best algorithm to compare a list of three dimensional items?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list of items and each item has three attributes (height, width and depth).
I need to compare those items, and I wrote this pseudocode algorithm:

```
For i =0 to List[].Count  
    For m=i+1 to List[].Count
            If List(i). Height =List(m). Height then
                 If List(i).width=List(m).width &
                 List[i].depth != List[m].depth then
                     Result_List[].Add(List[i])

                  End if
            End if
   End for
End for
```

Is there any better algorithm to do the same job?
I would really appreciate it if you can provide some analysys for the suggested algorithm.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? If you are trying to remove all elements with different depths, but same width and height, then sure, this is fine.

Comment: "Compare" for what purpose? With what objective in mind?

Comment: @AnT Yes , to pick the items that have same height and width but different depth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with that approach

Unless you are open to other data structures that would "partition" your data into "boxes of same width, depth, height", then you can micro-optimize by moving around which conditionals are compared first. You only want to continue on when the depths are not equal, so compare that first.

```
results = List[]

for i -> 0 .. len(elements)
  for j -> i+1 .. len(elements)
    if elements[i].depth != elements[j].depth
      if elements[i].width = elements[j].width & elements[i].height = elements[j].height
        results.add(elements[i])

return results
```

Comment: Consider - what happens if n is 10? 100? 1000? 10000? A number of years ago I took over maintenance of an app from the original developer, who moved on to gr$$ner pastures, and a short while later the users started complaining that a particular operation was taking "a long time". A little digging later I found a nice little nested loop (with a couple embedded SQL queries, no less!) which usually had 10-20 elements to search, but once in a while had 1000 elements to search. A short rewrite later and the users were happy once again. Lesson: nested loops are BA-A-A-A-AD! :-)

Comment: I agreed nested loops are bad and that ideally, let's say this data could be shoved into a columnar database with the 3 columns. A simple query with a `GROUP BY height, width` could get that, and then `UNIQUE depth`. I'm guessing that would have similar a performance hit than doubling the iteration over the elements.

Comment: is There another way without nested loops?

Answer (score -2):

Your doing an O(n) scan which is hard to beat and good enough unless you have huge  numbers of elements+.

If your trying to do more with x,y,z eg search etc then you should use an octrees structure as it will be more efficient than a list.

Comment: It's `O(n * (n - 1))` = `O(n^2)`, though.